# Vector import to Weaviate of stock data using .net?

Tags: .net, artificial-intelligence, weaviate

I want to upload price data of financials like stocks, crypto to Weaviate. I want to use .net for this as the language.

Has anyone already tried to do this an have an example?

Comment: I am aware of this Python variant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70326786/python-pandas-datareader-import-historical-stock-data-in-euro

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any ideas re how to load or manipulate data in .NET, but I know there's a client for it. Have you seen this? https://github.com/searchpioneer/weaviate-dotnet-client

Comment: Ah, Thanks indeed this is a good reference project to get some inspiration from!